# eOnSuccess will be executed even if the Ajax.actionlink did not succsfully execute & also the OnSuccess will not display alerts if using firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following ajax.actionlink that is responsible for deleting answer objects:-

```
    <td>
             @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
            new { id = answer.AnswersID },
              new AjaxOptions
              {

                  Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",
                  HttpMethod = "Post",
                  UpdateTargetId = @answer.AnswersID.ToString(),
                  OnSuccess = "deleteconfirmation",
OnFailure = "deletionerror"
              })


        </td>
```

and the following deleteconfirmation.js :-

```
function deleteconfirmation() {
    jAlert('The Answer was deleted succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation');
        $(this).remove();
}
```

were the ajax.actionlink will call the folloiwng action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var a = repository.FindAnswer(id);

            repository.DeleteAnswer(a);
            repository.Save();
            return Content("");
assessments.");
        }
```

but i am facing the following problem:-

1. if i delete an object using firefox web browser then the `jAlert('The Answer was deleted succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation');` will not be shown , while it will be shown using IE, so what might be the reason?
2. i browse to the intended web page whice show an answer object, then i manually delete the answer object from the database, after that i click on the delete ajax link behind the deleted object (before refreshing the page), so i was expecting that the onfailure script will be executed but it did not , rather a null exception was raised.
3. Is there a way to provide a jquery confirm box instead of the `Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",`
   BR

****Edit:- **** thanks a lot for your detailed answer but i have the following points that need to be clarifiy:-

> In your Delete controller action you are returning an empty content
>   (return Content("")) and yet you have defined an UpdateTargetId =
>   @answer.AnswersID.ToString() in your link which makes FireFox throw an
>   error because you cannot insert an empty content into the DOM

i am returning an empty string from the action method becuase i do not need to display anything to the user after the deletion ,since  i am removing the deleted object from the DOM using $`(this).remove();` so what should the partial view `_foo` contains in this case?

> If on the other hand you handle this exception on the server and
>   consume it without leaving it propagate and return a 200 HTTP status
>   code

but in my case the action method is not handling the null pointer exception, but on the other hand the Ajax.Actionlink onFailure will not be executed if the null pointer exception was raised!!.

thanks again for ur help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) if i delete an object using firefox web browser then the
>   jAlert('The Answer was deleted succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation');
>   will not be shown , while it will be shown using IE, so what might be
>   the reason?

In your `Delete` controller action you are returning an empty content (`return Content("")`) and yet you have defined an `UpdateTargetId = @answer.AnswersID.ToString()` in your link which makes FireFox throw an error because you cannot insert an empty content into the DOM - it just doesn't make sense. I guess IE is a little more tolerant to this kind of errors. I guess that in IE, while you don't get an error, the given DOM element doesn't refresh at all after the delete.

So you will have to return some actual content such as a partial view from your delete controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var a = repository.FindAnswer(id);
    repository.DeleteAnswer(a);
    repository.Save();
    return PartialView("_Foo");
}
```

Now the contents of this partial view will be used to refresh the given DOM element.

> 2) i browse to the intended web page whice show an answer object, then
>   i manually delete the answer object from the database, after that i
>   click on the delete ajax link behind the deleted object (before
>   refreshing the page), so i was expecting that the onfailure script
>   will be executed but it did not , rather a null exception was raised.

If an exception, is thrown on your server side and a 500 HTTP status code is returned the OnFailure callback will be invoked. If on the other hand you handle this exception on the server and consume it without leaving it propagate and return a 200 HTTP status code, it will be the `OnSuccess` callback that will execute even if there was an error on the server.

> 3) Is there a way to provide a jquery confirm box instead of the
>   Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?"

Sure, just use `OnBegin` instead of `Confirm`:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    "Answer",
    new { id =  answer.AnswersID },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        UpdateTargetId = answer.AnswersID.ToString(),
        OnBegin = "deletebegin",
        OnSuccess = "deleteconfirmation",
        OnFailure = "deletionerror"
    }
)
```

and in your `deletebegin` callback:

```
function deletebegin() {
    // Show whatever confirmation you want here and return true
    // to proceed with the AJAX request and false to cancel it.

    // As an example I am using the standard confirm js method but
    // you could really use whatever you like

    var shouldProceed = confirm('Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?');

    return shouldProceed;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, the problem is that the OnBegin will not work as Confirm; because the ObBegin script will be executed at the same time the object will be deleted and removed from the DOM regardless of weather the user select "OK" or "Cancel"....

Comment: @johnG, the OnBegin callback is executed before the AJAX call. If you return false from it the AJAX call won't be executed. And it's only after the AJAX call succeeds that the DOM is updated.